# Error: Thing is not a known valid target type for the itemReviewed property

Tags: php, html, css, structured-data

It showsError: Thing is not a known valid target type for the itemReviewed property.for the below code. Kindly help.

```
<div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/AggregateRating" style="color: #333; margin: 10px auto; font-size: 12px;display: inline-block;width: 100%;line-height: 20px;">
<span itemprop="itemReviewed" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing" style="color: #333; margin: 20px auto; font-size: 12px;">
    <span itemprop="name">#</span>&nbsp;
</span>
<span>
    <a href="https://#/testimonials.html" title="Check all reviews" rel="nofollow" style="color: #333; margin: 20px auto; font-size: 12px;">Reviews</a>
</span><br>
<span itemprop="ratingValue" style="color: #333; margin: 20px auto; font-size: 12px;">5</span> rating, out of 
<span itemprop="bestRating" style="color: #333; margin: 20px auto; font-size: 12px;">5</span> based on 
<span itemprop="ratingCount" style="color: #333; margin: 20px auto; font-size: 12px;">1127</span> Patients.
```

Comment: Please add sample code or more details

Answer (score 0):

Google supports only a subset of types for itemReviewed if you want to get rich results:

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/review-snippet#review-properties

The documentation is a bit confusing as it does mention Thing for the value of itemReviewed, but then lists what specific types it can be.

Comment: I tried using https://schema.org/Course and it's the same result